# How to have a pointer to a C function inside a C++ class?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

In a C++ class, I need to call functions that come from a dynamically loaded library. I get the function pointers like this:

```
typedef void (*TDef_libfunc)(); // also tried extern "C" typedef void (*TDef_libfunc)();

my_libfunc = (TDef_libfunc)dlsym(thelibrary, "libfunc");
```

(The lib function is loaded, I see it in the debugger.)

my_libfunc is declared as a member variable like this:

```
TDef_libfunc my_libfunc;
```

From within a member function of that class, I try to call my function pointer like this:

```
my_libfunc();
```

But it crashes... Am I doing this right? Is it possible to have a member variable that is a pointer to a C function?

Comment: Yes, its possible. Perhaps you got the calling convention wrong?

Comment: There's no problem having a function pointer member in a class, your problem stems from something else.

Comment: Everything here is fine. Did you check that the function was actually loaded?

Comment: @K-ballo: I also thought of a calling convention problem. I tried using extern "C" in my function pointer typedef but it did not change anything. How would I specify the calling convention?

Comment: Do the proper return checking as suggested on [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/5257/)

Comment: The function is loaded, I confirm.

Comment: Is the C function compiled with a compatible compiler and is using a compatible set of libraries?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `libfunc` in the loaded library.

Comment: @Dan: I believe so and doing the same function loading from this library directly in main() does not cause any problems. My problems happen when I do this inside a class.

Comment: @JohnVolkya: With no `extern "C"`?

Comment: Post a stack trace from a debugger such as gdb.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, it has extern "C". I tried it also in my typedef but it did not change anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple library compiled using gcc (if you compile will g++ you will need to add extern "C").

```
// test-lib.c
// gcc -Wall -g -shared -fpic test-lib.c -o test-lib.so
#include <stdio.h>

void
libfunc()
{
    printf("Hello World - Message sent from the libfunc() function.\n");
}
```

Simple program that will load the above library (path and function hard-coded).

I had a seg fault because I had an declared fn_ as a pointer.

```
// test-loadlib.cpp
// g++ -Wall -g test-loadlib.cpp -o test-loadlib -ldl
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*TDef_libfunc)(void);

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() : lib_(NULL) , fn_(NULL) { }

    ~TestClass() { if (lib_ != NULL) dlclose(lib_); }

    bool
    load_library()
    {
        if ((lib_ = dlopen("./test-lib.so", RTLD_NOW)) == NULL)
            return false;

        // From man page, this is correct way to store function ptr.
        *(void**) (&fn_) = dlsym(lib_, "libfunc");
        if (fn_ == NULL)
        {
            dlclose(lib_);
            lib_ = NULL;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void
    call_func()
    {
        if (fn_ != NULL)
            (*fn_)();
        else
            std::cout << "Function not loaded.\n";
    }

private:
    void*         lib_;
    TDef_libfunc  fn_;    // Don't include '*' - it will segfault.
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TestClass  tc;

    if (tc.load_library())
        tc.call_func();
    else
        std::cout << "Failed to load library.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I tested and compiled this under Ubuntu 10.04 using the compiler from the repository.

Comment: However you really should have used `extern "C" { ... }` around your typedef. Yes, it may work without, but then, are you completely sure there's not some arcane case where it does make a difference? Or that it doesn't make a difference on another platform?

Comment: I tried to minimize the amount of code needed to show it worked. Does `extern "C" { ... }` do more than prevent name mangling?  To load the function, I only need to know the name - mangled or not.

Comment: But minimizing to incorrectness is never a good idea. After all it would have been just about 15 extra keystrokes.

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect.  `extern "C" { ... }` would wrap around the function in the library not the code loading the library. If I had a C object file and wanted to link it to a C++ file, I would need to use `extern "C"` for function declarations so C++ could load them.  Since that is not what is happening here, it doesn't apply.

Comment: `extern "C"` specifies the linkage, which includes calling conventions. Now on Linux it happens that C and C++ calling conventions are exactly the same, and `extern "C"` only affects the name mangling. But that is in no way guaranteed by the standard. There could well be an implementation where the C++ calling convention takes advantage of the fact that in C++ you need to give prototypes for all functions you call, in order to make optimizations not possible without prototypes. In that case, calling a C function through a C++ function pointer could lead to incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks @celtschk, I had forgotten about differences between other compilers (e.g. Pascal) and how they push/pop things off the stack.